# Anything sync daemon for Ubuntu?

Tags: memory, disk-usage

Is there a utility providing similar functionality to [Anything sync daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anything-sync-daemon) for 64bit Ubuntu? Preferably in the repository or with a PPA.

In particular, I'd like to stop Firefox from constantly waking my disk up so even an equivalent to the [Profile sync daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Profile-sync-daemon) would suffice.